# How do I make my JavaScript project more manageable?

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm building a JS library that can attach to and interacts with to any HTML5 Canvas element context.

However, the project is starting to get extensive with lots of files and thousands of lines of code. Each file represents a different object/module. Each file is currently laid out like this, and I'd really like to preserve some semblance of this style:

```
Object = function() { 
    // constructor
}

Object.prototype.method1 = function() {
    // Logic
}

Object.prototype.method2 = function() {}; // .... etc
```

And in the development version of the HTML I have a bajillion script tags (one for each file) that need to be in a precise order (for dependencies). I realize that this is very inefficient, and not very maintainable.  But I'm not sure what is the best direction to go in to try and make my project easier to build and maintain. Port to NodeJS for the convenience of the tools and CommonJS module system? Convert to RequireJS? I'm just starting to read about Grunt, is that useful for my situation?

Improving my organization and introducing some sort of build system are both things I've put off doing for a while. And man do I regret it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need a module system**.

RequireJS, with the RequireJS optimizer, is the canonical solution here. You can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) if you're more Node.js-leaning, or use the cjsTranslate feature of the RequireJS optimizer if you dislike the AMD cruft (`define(function (require, exports, module) { ... });`)---possibly in conjunction with [Cajon](http://tagneto.blogspot.com/2012/06/cajon-browser-module-loader-for.html) in development.

---

A build tool, like Grunt, is not the most important factor here. That is useful mainly when you have multiple build steps---e.g., run the RequireJS optimizer, and then compile your SASS to raw CSS, then concatenate the CSS, then turn your images into sprites, then... etc.

Comment: As a suggestion, http://yeoman.io/ combines build tooling, RequireJS, a test server, and some other neat toys into an accessible bundle. It definitely helped me untangle my big project without too much fuss.

Comment: @Zugbo good suggestion. I haven't played with yeoman personally, but it does look like it wants to solve these problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that for every one of those `<script>` tags, the browser is having to make one more HTTP request - even if it's being loaded from cache, the browser has to ask the server if the file's been changed.

I would suggest writing a small program, such as this PHP script, to combine all your .js files into one:

```php
<?php
function loop($dir="./") {
    $ret = Array();
    foreach(glob($dir."*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $d) $ret = array_merge($ret,loop($d));
    foreach(glob($dir."*.js") as $f) $ret[] = $f;
    return $ret;
}
$out = fopen("__main.js","w");
foreach(loop() as $file) {
    if( $file == "./__main.js") continue; // don't include "main" script
    fwrite($out,file_get_contents($file));
}
fclose($out);
?>
```

Now you can just have one `<script>` tag pointing to that `__main.js` file and all your scripts will be there.

If your scripts must be in a certain order, then you're doing something wrong. If you're only defining objects in these files, it shouldn't depend on other ones since references should be in methods (consider using an `init` method, for instance).

Comment: This is purely local development, so I didn't care about extra http requests (but now its annoying purely from a a maintenance perspective), anything that would actually go to production would be concatenated and minified. Also, I use prototypal inheritance for some objects, and so superclasses must be defined before subclasses. Which is why I need the order to be specific in some cases. I'm really looking for more of an entire system to make my life easier rather than a simple script.